# How come I am getting weird results with istream::get(char*, streamsize n, char delim)?

Tags: c++, c++builder, ifstream

I am reading in a file with a format similar to:

```
TIME, x, y, z
00:00:00.000 , 1, 2 , 3
00:00:00.001 , 2 , 3 , 4
```

etc, and code similar to the following:

```
std::ifstream& istream;
char buffer[15];
double seconds, hours, mins; // initialised properly in real code

// to read in first column
istream.get(buffer, 14, ',');

int scanned = std::sscanf(buffer, "%d:%d:%lf", &hours, &mins, &seconds);
```

It reads in the first column fine for most of the time. However, occasionally the sscanf fails, and when I check what is in the buffer using the Codegear debugger I see that it has read in `\000:00:023` for example. For some reason it is collecting a null character ,`\0`, at the front. When I look in the text file, it appears to be the same format as all the other time values that were read in correctly. Why is it occasionally adding a null character? And is there a work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have read a blank line, or you are trying to read past the end of the file.

The first character is `\0`, which signifies the end of the string.

Any characters after that are untouched memory.

Comment: But it only happens to some of the time values that I read in and the formatting is consistent for all the rows. So why is it reading a blank line?

Comment: Does a hex editor verify that there are not nulls in the text file?  Are you checking istream.eof()?  istream.bad()?  istream.fail()?

Comment: Yes - it was actually correctly reading the last time value. However, the error was occurring on the next loop when it would try and read past the end of the file. I was confused as the debugger was showing the last time value read in the buffer with the `\0` at the front of it.

Answer (score 2):

try this and see..

```
ifstream inpfile("sample.txt");
char buffer[15];
inpfile.ignore(80, '\n');
while (!inpfile.eof())
{

    inpfile.get(buffer, 14, ',');
    int hrs, mins;
    double secs;
    hrs = mins = secs = -1;
    sscanf_s(buffer, "%d:%d:%lf", &hrs, &mins, &secs);
    cout << "hrs:" << hrs << "\t"
        << "mins:" << mins << "\t"
        << "secs:" << secs 
        << endl;
    inpfile.ignore(80, '\n');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

most likely you have a trailing comma in your input file somewhere. or perhaps more than 14 characters of whitespace after the last number on a line.